# Mat::copyTo() function error

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to copy a smaller image at the center of a bigger image.
Here is the code:

```
src.copyTo(dest(Rect(50,50,src.cols,src.rows)));
```

where both `src` and `dest` are Mats, `dest` is 5 times bigger than `src` and assuming 50,50 to be the center of dest.

I am getting the following errors:

```
no matching function for call to 'cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::Mat)'
```

Any fixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try constructing your destination Mat after calling `copyTo`:

```
Mat roi = dest(Rect(50,50,src.cols,src.rows));
src.copyTo(roi);
```

This should work. `copyTo` accepts one OutputArray as a parameter. The proxy classes InputArray and OutputArray are defined as `const` references, hence the error. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=copyto#inputarray

Comment: Thank you very very much for the fast response and fix, that did the trick